# Quadrilateral with two parallel sides and a bisector

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given a quadrangle $ABCD$ where two of the sides $AD$ and $BC$ are parallel with lengths $a$ and $b$ respectively.
Futhermore we have the midpoint $M$ on $AB$ and $K$ on $CD$. The diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersects the line $KM$ at points $P$ and $Q$ respectively. I am tasked with expressing the distance $PQ$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

This is problem in Euclidean geometry I've been stuck on for quite a while. So far I've narrowed it down to two cases: one where we get a trapezoid like figure and one where we the angles  at $B$ and $D$ are greater than 90 degrees. 
I did two quick figures in paint (I apologize for my artistic qualities beforehand) to illustrates this.

[image]
[image]

So far I've been able to show that the two triangles formed by the diagonals and $AD$ and $BC$ are similar but that is a far as I'm able to get.

My current idea is to try to show that $KM$ is parallel with either of the two parallel line. Then the triangle formed by the diagonals and their intersection with $KM$ will be similar to both the other two triangles I found. This should enable me to find an expression for $PQ$

However I've been unable to find a way to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** To prove $MK$ is parallel to both $AD$ and $BC$.

Draw the line through point $K$ parallel to $AB$ and denote by $D'$ its intersection point with $AD$  and by $C'$ its intersection point with $BC$. Now, you have a quadrilateral $ABC'D'$ such that $AB$ is parallel to $C'D'$ by construction and $BC'$ is parallel to $AD'$ by the fact that $BC$ and $AD$ are parallel. What kind of quadrilateral is that? After that, what can you say about triangles $KDD'$ and $KCC'$, having in mind that $K$ is the midpoint of $CD$ and $BC$ is parallel to $AD$? Consequently, what can you say about the segments $KC'$ and $KD'$? How are they also related to $AB$ and its midpoint $M$?

Ok, as you discovered $KCC'$ and $KDD'$ are congruent and thus $D'K = C'K$ meaning that $K$ is the midpoint of $C'D'$. Quad $ABC'D'$ is a parallelogram because $AB$ is parallel to $C'D'$ by construction and $BC'$ is parallel to $AD'$ by the fact that $BC$ and $AD$ are parallel. Form here, look at $AMKD'$. we know by construction that $D'K$ is parallel to $AM$. But we also know that $$D'K = \frac{1}{2} D'C' = \frac{1}{2} AB = AM$$ because $D'C' = AB$ since $ABC'D'$ is a parallelogram and $K$ and $M$ are midpoints of $AB$ and $D'C'$ respectively. Therefore $D'K$ parallel to $AM$ and $D'K = AM$ implies that $AMKD'$ is a parallelogram too. Therefore, $MK$ is parallel to  line $AD' \equiv AD$ and consequently parallel to line $BC$ as well.

Comment: As |*DK*| = |*CK*|  and  all the angles are the same we get that triangles *DD'K* and *C'KC* are congruent. Hence |*D'K*| = |*C'K| = |AM| = |BM|.

Comment: However i do not quite see how this helps me. Does this help me show that the angles *MKC'* and *DD'K* are similar and therefore *AD'* is parallel with *MK*?

Comment: @OrganizerOfVictory I edited my post.

Comment: Yes! I never thought to regard *AMKD* as a parallelogram. This should give me bunch of similar triangles and the relations between the sides, which after some tinkering should yield the desired length. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

In *both* of your figures, $ABCD$ is a trapezoid (not merely trapezoid-like).
Your two cases are really the same unless you somehow assume in some step
of your proof that one of the angles $A, B, C,$ or $D$ is obtuse (or acute).
And you should not have to rely on any such assumption.

The cases I would cite first are $AB$ parallel to $CD$ ($AB \parallel CD$)
and $AB$ not parallel to $CD$ ($AB \not\parallel CD$).
If $AB \parallel CD$ then the answer should be relatively straightforward.
If $AB \not\parallel CD$ then you should be able to show that $a \neq b$,
so either $a < b$ or $a > b$.

For the step where you simply want to prove that $KM$ is parallel to
$AD$ and $BC$, you can assume without loss of generality that
$a < b$.
Extend $AB$ and $CD$ until they intersect at a point $E$.
Consider the triangles $ADE$, $BCE$, and $MKE$.
Prove that they are all similar to each other.